# How to build and install Boost libraries requiring separate building and installation on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, boost, installation, boost-log

I have recently upgraded from Boost 1.54 to 1.57.  But when I look in my lib directory where all my boost library files are located, I do not see libboost_log.so

I ran ./bootstrap.sh --show-libraries to see what should get installed and I received the following:

```
pdl@pdl-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/boost_1_57_0$ ./bootstrap.sh --show-libraries
Building Boost.Build engine with toolset gcc... tools/build/src/engine/bin.linuxx86_64/b2

The following Boost libraries have portions that require a separate build
and installation step. Any library not listed here can be used by including
the headers only.

The Boost libraries requiring separate building and installation are:
    - atomic
    - chrono
    - container
    - context
    - coroutine
    - date_time
    - exception
    - filesystem
    - graph
    - graph_parallel
    - iostreams
    - locale
    - log
    - math
    - mpi
    - program_options
    - python
    - random
    - regex
    - serialization
    - signals
    - system
    - test
    - thread
    - timer
    - wave
pdl@pdl-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/boost_1_57_0$
```

I need to install the log library.  It is a separate library that I downloaded separately as shown here:

[image]

I've been through the documents, Getting Started Guide, and looked on-line for how to install these separate libraries but I'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separate `boost::log` library shouldn't be necessary.

Instead, make sure that `boost::log` was build with your standard install of Boost.
If it wasn't, try making sure you have all of Boost's build dependencies installed
(if on Ubuntu, try `$ sudo apt-get build-dep boost1.54` or similar)
before re-running `./b2`.